# App insights: Can you concatenate two properties together?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-stream-analytics, kql, appinsights, ms-app-analytics

I have a custom event with a json (string) property called EventInfo. Sometimes this property will be larger than the 150 character limit set on event properties, so I have to split it into multiple properties, ie EventInfo0, EventInfo1, ect.

For example (shortened for simplicity)
`EventInfo0: [{ "label" : "likeButton", "stat]`,
`EventInfo1: [us" : "success" }]`

I found out how to look at EventInfo as a json in app insights like:

```
customEvents
 | where name == "people"
 | extend Properties = todynamic(tostring(customDimensions.Properties))
 | extend type=parsejson(Properties.['EventInfo'])
 | mvexpand type
| project type, type.label, type.status]
```

Is there a way I can concatenate EventInfo0 and EventInfo1 to create the full json string, and query that like above?

Comment: It's very nice if you can response to the answer below, like it works for you or not. And if it works, you should accept it as answer, as per [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, the 150 character limit is on the *key*, and not on the entire payload. So splitting as you're doing it may not actually be required.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/data-model-event-telemetry#custom-properties

[image]

that said, to answer your questions - while it's **not efficient** to do this at query time, the following could work:

```
datatable(ei0:string, ei1:string)
[
    '[{ "label" : "likeButton", "stat]', '[us" : "success" }]',
    '[{ "lab]', '[el" : "bar", "hello": "world" }]'
]
| project properties = parse_json(strcat(substring(ei0, 1, strlen(ei0) - 2), substring(ei1, 1, strlen(ei1) - 2)))
| project properties.label
```

```
properties_label
----------------
likeButton
bar
```

Comment: strcat was what I was looking for, thanks. I am very new to Kusto.